# Alternative API for google blog search API

Tags: api, search, google-api, blogs, deprecated

I am developing an application using Google blog search API. But google announcement says it has been deprecated and it will be available for another 1 year from here. So i am in trouble in continuing the developement. Is there any other API available for blog search?.

Comment: It looks Google doesn't offer a direct replacement for the Blog search API, you got to use the [Custom Search](https://developers.google.com/custom-search/) one.

Comment: Custom search - it's another, what I nned.

Answer (score 1):

I was in the same boat, luckily though I was able to get it around by implementing the custom search API instead as per https://developers.google.com/custom-search/

I found this helpful too: http://googlecustomsearch.blogspot.co.uk/